# Change window touch keyboard size

Tags: windows, windows-10

As the title discribed, is there a way to adjust Windows touch screen keyboard's size when on tablet mode?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the size of Touch Keyboard, trough Registry.

Create text file with :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Scaling]
"MonitorSize"="70"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7]

"EnableCompatibilityKeyboard"=dword:00000001
"KeyboardLayoutPreference"=dword:00000001
```

; (`KeyboardLayoutPreference` controls the default opened keyb. type)

Save it as ANSI/UTF-8 and with .reg extension. Run it.

I'm not sure if there will be needed to re- Sign In or restart.

Answer (score 0):

I am using "On-Screen Keyboard" when on tablet mode. I can resize the keyboard window and hence can change the keyboard's size. However, I needed to use my mouse/touchpad to resize the window. Just select and drag an edge or corner.

In case you are using a touch screen and don't want to use mouse/touchpad for any reason, first, touch on "Mv Up" or "Mv Down" key. That will move the keyboard window to the top or bottom of the screen accordingly. Then, try grabbing a side and expanding/shrinking it with a single finger touch. You will be able to resize the window.

[image]

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion. For some reason I have to use the touch screen keyboard of Window instead. Do you have any workaround ?

Comment: @manaclan yes, I am assuming you have touch screen. I grabbed a side of the keyboard window with my finger touch (just one finger, two wouldn't work.) and tried expanding/shrinking it. It worked just fine.